# how to run a private blockchain network with geth on other machines, such as server and client?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

i want to run private blockchain network , on the server I'm running:

```
geth --networkid 4224 --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "D:\mydirectory\private-network" --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --lightkdf --cache 16 --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec --allow-insecure-unlock
```

then on another machine I want to run the client, then my question is how to run the client on another machine and connect to the server?

Comment: What do you call a client ? Is it another geth node or something else ?

Comment: geth nodes are run on other computers and are connected to each other, for example like running geth nodes that are connected to each other but are different machines

Comment: I still do not understand: Do you want to run several nodes or do you want to connect any other kind of application via RPC ?

Comment: i want to run multiple nodes on different machines with the same genesis.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this comment: `i want to run multiple nodes on different machines with the same genesis.json`

To run multiple nodes, you have two solutions:

---

**Solution one**: Static nodes

One your second (or more) machine, instal geth and initiate the genesis like you did with the first one.

Into your `datadir/geth`, create a file named `static-nodes.json`.

This file should contain the enode(s) of the nodes you want, for example:

```
[
  "enode://f4642fa65af50cfdea8fa7414a5def7bb7991478b768e296f5e4a54e8b995de102e0ceae2e826f293c481b5325f89be6d207b003382e18a8ecba66fbaf6416c0@33.4.2.1:30303",
  "enode://pubkey@ip:port"
]
```

More information here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network#static-nodes

---

**Solution two**: bootnode(s)

While the first solution works, it is quite hard to maintain with a lot of nodes. This is why the bootnode exists: it is basically a node that tells other nodes connected to it: "hey, look, you can have a peer there".

I won't go into details here because it is a bit long and it has already been described here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster#private-network